# My data is not send to the url I want to send in a JSON format

Tags: java, android, json

Basically the problem is when I try to send the data by postman then my output is success but when I try to send the data by code then the problem is occured my data is not reached at the other end

```html
{ "message": 
    { "attributes" :
        { "authentication" : { "key" : "<Your API KEY>" },
          "profile_detail":{ "image" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA…………………… +KKKAf/Z" } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I tried volley, retrofit and currently try okhttp in android studio

```
final String json = "{ \"message\": { \"attributes\" : { \"authentication\" : { \"key\" : \"here API key\" }, \"profile_detail\":{ \"image\" : \"" + imageString + "\" } } } }";


final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, JSON);
    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                         //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error hun" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Log.e("error", e.toString());
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                         //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Log.e("response", response.body().string());

                     }
                 }
    );
```

Request Body:following JSON packet to be send:

Comment: I do not want to be rude, just asking, how much research did you do before asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject class instead of manually creating JSON

```
try {
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject attributes = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject authentication = new JSONObject();
        authentication.put("key", "your-key");
        JSONObject profile_detail = new JSONObject();
        profile_detail.put("image", "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA…………………… +KKKAf/Z");
        attributes.put("authentication", authentication);
        attributes.put("profile_detail", profile_detail);
        message.put("message", attributes);

        Log.w("json",message.toString());

    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```